# Image Transformation Filter

Tags: image, matlab, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I would like to transform an image like below

[input Image:](http://1drv.ms/1hMYbjF) http://1drv.ms/1hMYbjF

[output Image:](http://1drv.ms/1mVXSEr) http://1drv.ms/1mVXSEr

Any help or hint regarding this filter would be highly appreciated.

PS: Sorry i do not know the exact name of this filter/transformation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at OpenCV's [remap](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#remap) function. You are looking to do a geometric transform. You'll have to design the X,Y maps such that the pixels map in the way you have shown in your example.

Comment: Thanks, Indeed it's a great help. I will explore remap function and will come back if i need some more help